# Pyspark: Unpivot a dataframe with multiple columns without hardcoding the titles

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

What's a good way of unpivoting a dataframe without having to hard-code the column names, I've 50+ columns that need to switch to rows. I've tried the following, given this example:

**Using Python 2.7**

**df:**

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Category  |Col_A  |Col_B  |Col_C  |Col_D  |.......|
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Category1 |1      |0      |3      |0      |.......|
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Category2 |5      |0      |2      |0      |.......|
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Category3 |0      |6      |0      |4      |.......|
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Code:**

Determine the column (Col_X) names:

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
```

Gets the column count and creates the format 'Col_X', Col_X for each:

```
x = ""
cnt = 0
for c in cols:
    cnt += 1
    x += "'"+str(c)+"', " + str(c) + ", "
```

Removes last two characters:

```
x = x[:-2]
```

Creates the full expression:

```
xpr = "\"stack(" + str(cnt) + ", " + str(x) + ") as (Type,Value)\""
```

Output:

```
df_output = df.select("Category",expr(xpr))
```

But it returns something like this:

```
df_output.show()

+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Category  |stack(55, 'Col_A', Col_A, 'Col_B', Col_B....
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Category1 |
+----------+
|Category2 |
+----------+
|Category3 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by applying this on the expression buildup:

```
xpr = """stack({}, {}) as (Type,Value)""".format(cnt,x)
```